# Error clipping a raster with a shape layer "Attempt to create ADRG dataset with an illegal data type (Float32), only Byte supported by the format. "

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile

I try to clip a raster with a vector layer. When I try to do it, I get the error `"ERROR 1: Attempt to create ADRG dataset with an illegal data type (Float32), only Byte supported by the format."`

Can someone explain what this means and how I could fix this?

Edit: additional information:

-im using qgis 2.18.9 (tagged).

-the file formats are .tiff and .shp (poly)

-I'm working on a win10 x64 system

Comment: What software are you using

Comment: I'm using qgis 2.18.9 on a win10 x64 pc.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add those extra details, also can you provide details about the format of the input raster, and the vector layer, etc.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Debbie, take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251314/qgis-error-when-clipping-a-raster-with-a-shape-layer?noredirect=1#251314 which appears to be a similar problem with a successful fix.

Comment: @AndreJ I think that the thread suggested by Michael Stimson is the correct answer to this question (the command provided by QGIS is ADRG when it should be GTiff). The duplicated question that is suggested right now is addressing another problem with 64 bit-files that are not supported by QGIS. The answer in that thread is not applicable to this problem.