# QGIS Error when clipping a raster with a shape layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I am trying to clip a .tif file using the extent of a polygon (.shp). I am using the conventional Raster/Extraction/Clipper tool in QGIS 2.18.10. After choosing the appropriate settings, I get the following message:

```
ERROR 1: Attempt to create ADRG dataset with an illegal data type (Float32), only Byte supported by the format.
```

I am asking the exact same question as [uybfi](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/98508/uybfi) in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242759/error-clipping-a-raster-with-a-shape-layer-attempt-to-create-adrg-dataset-with?rq=1), which was marked as a duplicate for no apparent reason. The referred answer fails to address the issue. My raster is already in a supported format (Float32), and when changing the pixel depth with gdal_translate to other supported formats (e.g. Int32), I still get the this error.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: According to the docs http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#ADRG *Creation is possible, but it must be considered as experimental*. I suggest you find a different format, something like HFA  (ERDAS Imagine) or GTIFF driver to create your output.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Unless I am mistaken, this refers to using .gen  or .thf formats. I am using none of these two.

Comment: What output driver are you then using? the error message is about ADRG (ArcInfo Digitized Raster Graphic) format which means you're using the ADRG driver, albeit unintentionally. If you're doing it like this http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html can you include a screen shot of clipper window.

Comment: @MichaelStimson  I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "output driver". Is this different than the desired output format? and yes let me do a screen shot.

Comment: the driver is specified with -of in the command line which comes up in the window at the bottom of the tool just before execution. Each output format has a driver associated with it. I suspect your output is using the ADRG driver because it's the first alphabetically in the list but may not be what you're after.

Comment: screenshot is now up. I don't see any -of in that command line.

Comment: OH I SEE! you can clearly see -of ADRG, on the 3rd line, you need to change that to -of GTIFF to export a GeoTIFF. I think when you specify the output format you may need to select GeoTIFF in the filter to make the tool use the correct driver.

Comment: wow yes you are totally right, let me try that

Comment: Success! thanks for that! it's actually quite strange because it seems like **-of ADRG** appears only when I choose certain directories for my output file. I've just switched back and forth between the destination you see on the print screen and my desktop. Choosing the desktop sets **-of GTiff** automatically

Comment: That's great news, can you now answer your own question with the working screen shot please. I suspect GTIFF is the default for your desktop because of spaces in your path or some other limitation... I think in the save as dialog your output driver option would need to be specified but I don't have that version (or OS) installed to test it to answer this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue had to do with QGIS wrongfully inputing **-of ADRG** instead of **-of GTiff** in the command line when choosing the output file destination. Below is a screenshot of the clipper window properly set-up to successfully perform the clip operation. Thanks to @MichaelStimon for resolving this.

[image]

Comment: To solve the issue on Windows, you have to remove a registry entry, see https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16979. I'm not sure where the stuff is saved in Linux or MacOS.